# Unsupported methods in Symfony

Tags: php, symfony, google-2fa

I am implementing in my symfony project [2Fa](https://symfony.com/bundles/SchebTwoFactorBundle/current/index.html) authentication with the help of the official documentation. All good until I try to customize the conditions so that the user is forced to go through the 2Fa form, using the documentation [method](https://symfony.com/bundles/SchebTwoFactorBundle/current/custom_conditions.html).

The problem starts when in the function `shouldPerformTwoFactorAuthentication` I start to implement code as if it were a common function, I try do this:

```
public function shouldPerformTwoFactorAuthentication(AuthenticationContextInterface $context, ManagerRegistry $doctrine, UserInterface $userInterface): bool
    {
        $entityManager = $doctrine->getManager();
        $user = $entityManager->getRepository(User::class)->findOneBy(['email' => $userInterface->getUserIdentifier()]);
        if ($user->isIsGoogleEnabled()) {
            return false;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
```

As you can see I try to customize when to make it work and when not, but I get this error:

`Method 'App\Controller\TwoFactorConditionController::shouldPerformTwoFactorAuthentication()' is not compatible with method 'Scheb\TwoFactorBundle\Security\TwoFactor\Condition\TwoFactorConditionInterface::shouldPerformTwoFactorAuthentication()'.intelephense(1038)`

I've been searching the internet with no results that work for me, until i found [this](https://symfony.com/doc/current/service_container/parent_services.html).

I have made so many attempts at this that I will not post them, if someone can guide me, I appreciate your time, thanks!

Comment: It appears you've added `ManagerRegistry $doctrine, UserInterface $userInterface` to the method's signature, those chould be added to the constructor instead, I think

Answer (score 0):

This will work using `__construct()` method

```
private EntityManagerInterface $entityManager;
private UserInterface $userInterface;

public function __construct(EntityManagerInterface $entityManager, UserInterface $userInterface)
{
  $this->entityManager = $entityManager;
  $this->userInterface = $userInterface;
}

public function shouldPerformTwoFactorAuthentication(AuthenticationContextInterface $context): bool
{        
  $user = $this->entityManager->getRepository(User::class)->findOneBy(['email' => $this->userInterface->getUserIdentifier()]);
  if ($user->isIsGoogleEnabled()) {
    return false;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
```